# Do not output category and tag URLs

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, urls, tags, seo

I'd like to use WordPress as CMS without blog functionality.

I use some custom post types with categories and other taxonomies, for building up an [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) filter.

My question: Is it possible to do this without WordPress automatically genarating all the URLslike:

```
/custom-tag/
/custom-tag/custom-tag-name#01
/custom-/custom-tagname#02

/custom-category/
/custom-category/custom-category-name#01
/custom-category/custom-category-name#02
```

Because I do not need them for showing up all my contents. And they should not linked in Google SERPS, too.

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33872205/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

your theme will have certain templates, that will render pages in certain ways.

see [template hierachy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarch) , you could remove these (the default behaviour is to then resort to `index.php`, from their you could add some redirect rules for any mention of 'tag' or 'category' to redirect to another page.

This could, though, ruin your site's functionality so will need some testing.